# html code broken on IE broswer only

Tags: html, internet-explorer, special-characters

I'm trying to insert a star in my html using the following HTML code:

`&#9733;` (★)

It works on every major browser, except IE. IE displays weird characters. I'm using UTF-8 as my page encoding.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What is your Doctype - and which version(s) of IE is broken?

Comment: Works for me in IE 8, though I had to remove the space between the & and the #.

Comment: Also, define "weird characters". And which font you're trying to use.

Comment: I see a star and I am running IE8!

Comment: I think the space was inserted to prevent it from just turning into a star. Fixed.

Comment: I get the same problem with Microsoft word i guess it is a window related problem but it doesn't affect other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⋆ `<span style="font-family: arial unicode MS;font-size:200%;">&#8902;</span>`


the working example here http://jsfiddle.net/3Waym/